# How to find the position of every instance of a character in a list

Tags: python, list

I have a program where I need to identify the location of every instance of the letter A in a quote. Something like I would do with `quote.index("A")`, but I need *every* instance of `A`, not just the first.

I know this question has been asked before but I'm very, very new to Python and I'm having trouble understanding the answers to those questions.

If anyone could give me a dumbed down explanation of how to do this, I'd be incredibly thankful because I'm utterly lost.

Comment: If you don't show the answers you've read and highlight the bits you don't understand, then we have no hope in explaining it in a way that makes any more sense than what you've read.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: I'm not sure what you're thanking me for. Please edit your question so that you include the details I suggested. People are happy to help if it's clear what exactly we're supposed to be helping with.

Comment: loop over the items and indexes and pull out the indexes for those items equal to your character, simple `[idx for idx,char in enumerate(quote) if char == "A"]`

Comment: It is unfortunate that this was marked as a duplicate as I suspect it doesn't give you the explanation you were looking for. Please be sure to include all the relevant info when you ask another question so that it's clear exactly what you're stuck on.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly, you have a string and you want to keep all A's locations in e different array.

Then you can try something like that.

```
quote = "some quote"
locs = []
for i in range(len(quote)) : 
    if quote[i] == 'A' :
        locs.append(i)
print(locs)
```